# MySQL data recovery with INNODB

Tags: mysql

Recently our server got shutdown unexpectedly and next time when I tried to start mysql it was giving error. We did not have any data backup, so we just copied our data folder to some safe location. I have ib log files and ib data files along with all the database names with frm and ibd files. How can I restore my databases?

I can see my database and table names in MySQL Workbench, but when I query the table, it says that the table does not exist.

Comment: Is your server windows or linux ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide a bit more details (editing the question): Did you copy the files before or after the crash? To the same PC? Windows/Linux? What errors do you get (see the logs)? 
Btw: I'm not sure if this question is more suitable for http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I am using windows. I copied files after the crash.  I also have the following error when starting mysql. The log sequence numbers 39493811412 and 39493811412 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 39493811432 in the ib_logfiles

Answer (score 1):

These steps helped me in a very similar case:

1. Set [`innodb_force_recovery = 1`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html) in the my.cnf configuration to forcibly start InnoDB. Don't forget to actually (re)start the service. MySQL should be running now.
2. Use [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) to create an SQL dump
3. (Optionally) Use [pt-show-grants](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-show-grants.html) to additionally dump grants
4. Reinstall the database, or delete ibdata and ib_logfile files (see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23361/innodb-force-recovery-when-innodb-corruption)
5. Import both SQL dumps: the actual database dump, and the grants dump